# RedisGears write-behind using DynamoDB

Tags: caching, redis, redisgears

Is DynamoDB a compatible option with RedisGears?
In terms of a write-behind strategy, DynamoDB would be the backing DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to Dynamo DB from a RedisGears recipe as write behind cache pattern. Any target that has a python or java API would work.

Redis (the company) offers Redis Data Integration Write Behind, a product that allows you to create write behind pipelines without coding.
We do not yet support Dynamo DB but should be easy to add if customers wants it

Comment: Thanks!  Just to clarify, something similar to one of these examples?  Surprised there is not an AWS example

https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync/tree/master/examples